# How does our Prediction model handle new incoming Unseen-data which is not scaled , not one hot encoded nor PCA has not been done on it?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, pca, preprocessor

Let's say I have a training set with a dataframe.shape of (1000,500) with numeric, nominal and ordinal variables. Now I scale, One-Hot-Encode and do PCA on the data. I find that the first 6 components capture most of our variance of the data.

Now I reduce the shape of our data frame to (1000,6).

Then I do train_test_split, create a prediction model and do my predictions on the test_data and get the metrics.

Our model can handle the test_data because I've done the pre-processing(scale, One-hot-encode, PCA) before performing the Train_test_split.

Now let's say I get new unseen-data coming in. I feed it to our model. Since our new unseen-data has categorical-Variables and shape of (n,500) it Rejects it.

How do I do pre-process my new incoming data without explicitly pre-processing every time my model gets new unseen-data.

Comment: Question is too vague to be answerable

Comment: You need to preprocess your new data. I don't know what you mean by "explicitly".

Comment: by "explicitly" I mean let's say I deploy my model on a website and I get some new data to predict on. So every time I get new data I do the preprocessing again step by step then pass it to the model? what if the data is coming in continuously how do I preprocess it? Sorry, I'm new to everything I'm trying my best to word my question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to save the transformation made by the scaling operation, the encoding and by the PCA to be able to apply these transformations and the new data, giving you a shape (n, 6), allowing you to use your model.
To do that, the new categorical data must not contain categories !!

Using a sklearn Pipeline can be useful (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html).

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot.